# react firebase firestore insert json

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I  am using react with firebase firestore to insert a complete collection with documents that does not already exist in firebase firestore .

With my code however no collection is inserted and I get no error as if nothing happened.

This is the code that returns my json

createJson.js

```
const jsonArray = [{name:"Bill" , age : "5"} ,{name:"Jom" , age : "3"} ]
return jsonArray;
```

insertJson.js

```
import 'firebase/firestore';
const db = firebase.firestore();
export const insertJson = (jsn)=>{
    
  try{
    jsn.forEach(itm=>{
      let id = db.collection("doctors").doc().id;
       db
      .collection("doctors")
      .doc(id)
      .set(itm)
      .then(doc=>{
        console.log("Doc inserted with " +doc.id);
      })
    });
  }catch(err){
    console.log("Error : " +err);
  }

}
```

App.js

```
useEffect(()=>{
   const j = createJson();
   insertJson(j);
},[])
```

So in other words no collection is created with my script with the docs inside .

I would appreciate your help .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the Firestore [`add()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#add) method and [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) as follows:

```
export const insertJson = (jsn) => {
    try {
      const promises = [];
      jsn.forEach((itm) => {
        promises.push(db.collection('doctors').add(itm));
      });
      Promise.all(promises).then((results) => {
        console.log(results.length + ' doctors added');
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Error : ' + err);
    }
}
```

or, with [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
export const insertJson = (jsn) => {
    try {
      Promise.all(jsn.map((itm) => db.collection('doctors').add(itm))).then(
        (results) => {
          console.log(jsn.length + ' doctors added');
        }
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Error : ' + err);
    }
}
```

---

If the number of doctors is less than 500 you could also use a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes).

```
export const insertJson = (jsn) => {
    try {
      const batch = db.batch();
      jsn.forEach((itm) => {
        const docRef = db.collection('doctors').doc();
        batch.set(docRef, itm);
      });
      batch.commit().then((results) => {
        console.log('doctors added');
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Error : ' + err);
    }
}
```